Clarifications involving topologist's sine curve
The typical topologist's sine curve $S$ contains a range on the $y$-axis and the function $\sin(1/x)$,
\begin{equation}\label{1}\tag{1}
X = \{(0,y)| -1 \leq y \leq 1 \}, \quad Y = \{(x, \sin (1/x))| x>0\}
\end{equation}
I want to modify this a bit by changing the range of $X$ to $-1 < y < 1$ so that,
\begin{equation}\label{2}\tag{2}
X = \{(0,y)| -1 < y < 1 \}, \quad Y = \{(x, \sin (1/x))| x>0\}
\end{equation}
Intuitively, we might seem to think that $S$ is disconnected due to the fact that it contains sets that are disjoint $X \cap Y = \emptyset$. However, the definition for being connected is that, $S$ is connected only if we cannot write it as $A \cup B = S$ for some nonempty open sets $A$, $B$, and that $A \cap B = \emptyset$.
There is a proof for the connectedness of $S$ in $\eqref{1}$ which goes as follows (I'm not going to write the whole proof since that's not where my question lies): We assume (and know) that $Y$ is connected, we want to show that the closure of $Y$ labeled $\bar{Y}$ is connected. The closure $\bar{Y}$ will of course include $X$ so that $S = \bar{Y}$. Let us suppose that $\bar{Y}$ is disconnected, so there should be $A$, $B$ both nonempty open sets such that $A \cup B = \bar{Y}$ and $A \cap B = \emptyset$. The proof can be done to show in the end that either $A$ or $B$ must be empty, but this contradicts the assumption that both $A$, $B$ must be nonempty so $S = \bar{Y}$ must be connected.
The proof above involves arbitrary nonempty open sets $A$, $B$. We know that $X$ in $\eqref{1}$ is closed because it contains all of its boundary points, while $X$ in $\eqref{2}$ is neither closed nor open. Question, if we take the special case $A = X$, $B = Y$, is it correct to say that at least for this case, the condition $S = X \cup Y$ cannot be satisfied since $X$ in both cases is not open? Of course, that is why we need to show that there doesn't exist any nonempty open sets $A$, $B$ that can satisfy $A \cup B = S$ and $A \cap B = \emptyset$, not just for specific cases.
I have added $\eqref{2}$ to emphasize what I'm thinking about the arguments involving the topologist's sine curve, which involves $X$ not being open, such that whatever proof works for $\eqref{1}$ should also work for $\eqref{2}$. In other words, is it correct to say that whatever proof for the topologist's sine curve, it doesn't matter whether $-1 \leq y \leq 1$ or $-1 < y < 1$? My point is, it seems like whether the proofs for both cases will differ hinges on the fact that $X$ is not open.

$S = X \cup Y$. And your paragraph about $X, Y, S$ and their connectedness does not make sense. Check the definition of "connected".

@PaulFrost I'm not sure which part does not make sense but I'm guessing that it is my wording for which I pertain when I say connected. Originally I said "$X$, $Y$ are connected...", I changed it to "$S$ is connected...". Also, $S=X\cup Y$ is part of the standard definition right? In order to show that a set is disconnected, we should be able to find two disjoint nonempty open sets such that their union is the original set.

Do you know the difference between the union of two sets and their product?

@MoisheKohan Yes, oh, I see the issue. My notation for writing the topologist's sine curve is wrong. I modified the post.

None of your attempted arguments work. I suggest to read answers to this question and then adopt the proofs to your modified topological sine curve. (Incidentally, you should not use the same notation for different objects.)

You should not use the variables $X,Y$ when you write "$S$
is connected only if we cannot write it as $X∪Y=S$ ...".  $X$ and $Y$ are the spaces defined  above, in the connectedness-definition you have to allow any subspaces $U, V$ such that $S = U \cup V$.

@KritikerderElche Ah yes, I was focusing on the special case where the subspaces are $X$, $Y$, and that at least for that, it is impossible to establish $X \cup Y = S$. I have modified the post where I used $A$, $B$ instead of $U$, $V$. Thanks!
